# Why doesn't Rspec like my routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

In my application I have the concept of a topic.  A user can watch a topic.  I've created both a `WatchedController` and a `TopicController` to handle this.  Here's my routes:

```
resources :topics, :only => [:show, :index] do
  resource :watched, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Here's my failing sample Rspec test:

```
it "failing test" do
  post :create, :topic_id => @topic.id
end
```

When I run the spec, Rspec complains:

```
Failure/Error: post 'create', :topic_id => @topic.id
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:topic_id=>1, :controller=>"watched", :action=>"create"}
```

I've wasted an hour on this problem and I still can't figure out why it's not working.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `rake routes` at the command line to see what routes you have succeeded in defining, then either fix your route definitions to make sense or fix the code in your spec so it matches one of the routes in that list.

Comment: I didn't know that command existed.  It turned out watched was being pluralized to watcheds.  Thanks for the help.